# Pytorch Lightning repeats main script for each gpu

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

I have a single machine with two graphic cards. I'd like to use both for training my model. In an attempt to make my life easier, I'm using pytorch lightning.

When I run my script without gpus, everything works fine:

```
trainer = Trainer(gpus=None)
```

But I'd like to run it on multiple gpus. Confusingly, the [manual](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multi_gpu.html), first states that for one machine with multiple gpus you should use the 'dp' accelerator:

```
trainer = Trainer(gpus=2, accelerator='dp')
```

This starts the training session, but gives me an BroadcastBackward error that I only get when I try to use the dp accelerator (details below).

However the manual goes on to say that

> DP use is discouraged by PyTorch and Lightning. Use DDP which is more
> stable and at least 3x faster

Sounds great! So I do:

```
trainer = Trainer(gpus=2, accelerator='ddp')
```

But now when I run `trainer.fit`, the trainer starts a second process (`proc = subprocess.Popen(command, env=env_copy, cwd=cwd)` in ddp_accelerator.py.

On the one hand this is expected behaviour (one process per gpu), but on the other hand, it really literary reruns my main script (it's not just re-imported, so protecting with `if __name__ == "__main__":` doesn't help). My script is an optimisation scheme, with the following flow:

1. generate hyperparameters (based on results of earlier runs)
2. build, train, evaluate model: return performance measure
3. repeat from 1

This means that the second process gets different hyperparameters than the first, and this obviously throws an error.

Running on 1 gpu works fine by the way (training completes without errors):

```
trainer = Trainer(gpus=1, accelerator='ddp')
```

**How should I approach this problem? Stick with 'dp' and fix my BroadcastBackward error? Or stick with ddp, but how can I then fix the script duplication error?**

dp error details:

> In file X, Line X, in forward self.RMr.lerp_(Mr.squeeze(), exponential_average_factor) RuntimeError:
> Output 0 of BroadcastBackward is a view and is being modified inplace.
> This view is the output of a function that returns multiple views.
> Such functions do not allow the output views to be modified inplace.
> You should replace the inplace operation by an out-of-place one.

system details:
ubuntu, python: 3.8, pytorch-lightning: 1.0.7, pytorch: 1.6.0

Comment: Did you find a clean solution for this? I can't find any documentation that details why the script is being re-run.

Comment: I didn't find a real solution no

Comment: This is bugging me too. Running TFT via pytorch-forecasting and accelerator=ddp causes my main script to execute 4 times. I'm using 4x V100 gpus.